# Insert a changing number into a variable in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am defining some variables based on gui inputs, like so:

```
day1name=get(handles.day1name,'String');
day1start = datenum(get(handles.day1start,'String'));
day1end = datenum(get(handles.day1end,'String'));
day1data =Data(day1start:day1end,:);
day1datamodified = day1data*xyz
```

where day1datamodified is an nxn double array.

Basically I want to do this for several days, and several different entries. other than copy pasting this for my 15 days and making 15 different variables. is there a way to make the day1start say day2start, sort of like a day(i)start where i=1:15? then build a bigger structure array with little data arrays in it for each day that are labeled by the day1name entry which I can then manipulate and plot to my hearts content? I can probably use some for loop script for this, but how do I insert a variable into my variables?

edit: Data is a larger excel file i imported which has a time column that I am taking chunks of data from with the start/end times of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using dynamic field referencing in a structure containing all the variables for each day? Let's call the structure `Day`.

For each type of data (name, start, end...) use `sprintf` to create a string to provide to reference to the right element of the `handles` structure.

For instance, when `k = 1`:

```
DayName = day1name
```

and as such on the line right after you will get the `String`property of `handles.day1name` and so on for every variable, for each day.

```
for k = 1:15

DayName = sprintf('day%iname',k);
Day(k).name=get(handles.(DayName),'String'); %// The () are important here!

DayStart = sprintf('day%istart',k);
Day(k).start = datenum(get(handles.(DayStart),'String'));

DayEnd = sprintf('day%iend',k);
Day(k).end = datenum(get(handles.(DayEnd),'String'));

Day(k).data = Data(Day(k).start:Day(k).end,:);

Day(k).datamodified = Day(k).data*xyz 


end
```

Hope my explanations were clear enough!

Comment: i will give it a shot thanks! i was not sure how to put that variable in, but looks liek sprintf will do it.

Comment: it works! how do i call the big array of data that sits inside the structure so that I can plot it, find min max, etc. to it? the day(k).datamodified array.

Comment: Great! You can manipulate it as any array. Eg. `max(Day(1).datamodified)` or any function. You can also access data inside `datamodified` for example `Day(1).datamodified(1,:)` to get the first row.